# weird rosmake error with pr2_description package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build the pr2_description package on a ubuntu 12.04 machine with ros fuerte.

I get the following error, which I do not understand. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

```
$ rosmake pr2_description 
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pr2_description']                                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/rico/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121004-122817                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pr2_description'] to:
['pr2_description']                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> convex_decomposition [ make ]                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> ivcon [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< convex_decomposition ROS_NOBUILD in package convex_decomposition                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< ivcon ROS_NOBUILD in package ivcon                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                                                                                                                                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro                                                                                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser                                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                                                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_description [ make ]                                                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] All 34 linesr2_description: 0.5 sec ]                                                                                                                                 [ 1 Active 12/13 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package pr2_description
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  
  [rosbuild] WARNING: the file /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/cmake/xacro.cmake is being included automatically.  This behavior is deprecated.  The package containing that file should instead export the directory containing the file, and you should use rosbuild_include() to include the file explicitly.
  
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/cmake/xacro.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build
  cd build && make -l8

  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  [  0%] Generating ../meshes/shoulder_v0/convex/upper_arm_roll_L.obj

  make[3]: IVCON_PROG-NOTFOUND: Command not found

  make[3]: *** [../meshes/shoulder_v0/convex/upper_arm_roll_L.obj] Error 127

  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/media_files.dir/all] Error 2

  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rico/ros/workspace/pr2_description/build'

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pr2_description written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/rico/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121004-122817/pr2_description/build_output.log                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_description [FAIL] [ 0.56 seconds ]                                                                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pr2_description. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Built 13 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] /home/rico/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121004-122817
```

UPDATE: ros-fuerte-robot-model is already installed. Maybe the problem is something different altogether ... the reason why I installed and compiled this and other packages to my workspace is that they were required for another package and could not be found. But *$roscd robot_model* works fine and takes me to */opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/robot_model*. My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH looks good, too: */home/rico/ros/workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45096/weird-rosmake-error-with-pr2_description-package/) by [ricoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3309/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-04**:
Are you maybe using pr2_description from trunk? There is a pretty good chance that it only compiles under groovy. Try using the version from the fuerte branch if you really cannot install from debian packages: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_common/branches/pr2_common-1.8/

**Comment by [ricoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3309/ricoj/) on 2012-10-04**:
I have installed new packages using roslocate info PACKAGE >> .rosinstall and rosws update in my workspace.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-04**:
Please have a look at my updated answer. Get rid of your source installation and install it from debian packages: `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-common`

**Comment by [ricoj](https://answers.ros.org/users/3309/ricoj/) on 2012-10-04**:
okay, I installed the package I was originally interested in using

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-PACKAGE

this includes all dependencies and should fix the problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The system is unable to find `ivcon` which is part of the stack [robot_model](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_model). Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-robot-model
```

Note that you can get an already compiled version of pr2_description by installing the pr2_common debian pacakge:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-common
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2